# Array taking input for illegal index due to pointer defined

Tags: arrays, c, function, pointers, return-type

In below code, in main function if I remove "p = createHeap(n,a)", then its taking input normally till defined n. But if its not removed then array input (for loop) will go on taking input continuously (infinite loop). Not able to get the reason.

```
#include<stdio.h>

int * createHeap(int n, int *b);
void insert();
void delete();

int main() {
    int n,i,j;
    int *p;
    printf("Enter the size of array : ");
    scanf("%d",&n);
    
    int a[n];
    printf("\nEnter the elements of array: %d",n);
    
    for(i=0;i<n;i++) {
        scanf("%d",&a[i]);
    }
    printf("out");
    p = createHeap(n,a);                       // Problem in this line.
                                               //If removed then array will take input upto n
                                               // if not then input loop will be infinite.
    printf("\nsuccess");

return 0;

}

int * createHeap(int n, int *b) {
    int i,j,k;
    
    for(i=1;i<n;i++) {

        j=(i+1)/2 - 1;                                      //parent node
        k=i;
        while(j>=0) {
            if(b[k] > b[j])
                {
                    b[i] = b[i]+b[j];                       //swap
                    b[j] = b[i]-b[j];
                    b[i] = b[i]-b[j];
                }
            k=j;
            j=(i+1)/2 - 1;                                  //tracking parent node
        }       
    }
    
    return b;

}
```

Comment: The infinite loop is in `createHeap`.  You don't see the string "out" because you didn't add a newline to the end of the string.

Comment: to add to @dbush 's comment, console/terminal input and output is line buffered in nearly all modern systems, and is part of the POSIX spec, meaning that the 'print or scan' action is taken *after* the line ends, as you do when you press `[ENTER]` to send input to the program - except in output, you'll need the `\n` to represent end-of-line . Alternatively , you may `fflush(stdout)` to force printing , but maybe its easier to just to add the newline char.